# Remove elements of List<int> use View State in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I am meeting a problem about View State. Here my code:

```
public List<int> ListId
{
     get
     {
         return (List<int>)ViewState["ListId"];
     }
     set
     {
         ViewState["ListId"] = value;
     }
 }
protected void btAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState.Remove("ListId");
    foreach (TreeNode tn in tvFAQ.CheckedNodes)
    {
        if (tn.Checked)
        {
            Id = tn.ValuePath;
            ListId = PassId.ListId(Id);
        }
     }
     if(ListId!=null)
     {
        ListById();
     }
}
```

In function ListById() I will use "ListId.Count" but elements of ListId can not be remove, so when I do in a page, element of ListId wil be auto increase until I close page. Please help me remove elements of ListId after I click on button "Add". Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be removed.

You can try this

```
ViewState["ListId"] = null;
```

Comment: "ListId" is still having values